# Odd resizing of controls VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, autoresize

I have a listbox and a panel. In my forms resize event, my listbox is always form1.width * 0.5 and then the panel is also, but it doesnt work very well. I
They overlap at a certain point but in theory, they never should. Is there something wrong with my logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the margin property for both controls. If it's non-zero, then your controls may take up more width than the form's.